# If a feature gives proficiency in a skill you are proficient with, can you always choose any skill to replace that proficiency?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, character-advancement, proficiency

Page 125 of the PHB in the [rules for backgrounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Backgrounds) we have this statement:

> If a character would gain the same proficiency from two different sources, he or she can choose a different proficiency of the same kind (skill or tool) instead.

This statement is given in the context of character creation, and specifically skill proficiencies given by backgrounds.

Does this rule apply to any feature *gained at any level* that gives proficiencies, or only at first level?

This question was inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170440/62294) where a particular eldritch invocation could be made into a “choose any skill proficiency” feature, if the character already had proficiency in persuasion or deception.

Comment: Related: [How does the Cleric's Blessings of Knowledge feature interact with the rules for gaining proficiency when already proficient in a skill?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94758/48827)

Comment: While the question about Blessings of Knowledge is useful, it only incidentally answers this one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### The quoted text applies only to backgrounds

That text is found in chapter 4: Personality and Background which tells us right from the start that the rules found here *most likely* only apply to backgrounds.

Furthermore, the text in question states in full (emphasis mine):

> **Each background** gives a character proficiency in two skills. Skills are described in the Using Ability Scores section.
>
> In addition, **most backgrounds** give a character proficiency with one or more tools. Tools and tool proficiencies are detailed in the Equipment section.
>
> If a character would gain the same proficiency from two different sources, he or she can choose a different proficiency of the same kind (skill or tool) instead.

The previous two paragraphs are specifically about backgrounds so it makes sense to assume the third is as well.

---

Another reason to believe this is not a general rule is its location. Why would such a rule appear in the section on backgrounds and then not in the rules on "[Proficiency Bonus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#ProficiencyBonus)" where one would really expect to find it?

---

However, the greatest piece of evidence is various features that *do* let you choose another proficiency if you already have one:

The various Artificer subclasses grant you a tool proficiency, and *explicitly state* that if are already proficient in that tool you can pick a different tool to gain proficiency in.

If there were a general rule that acquiring the same proficiency again meant you could pick a new one, then there would be no need for this feature to state what it does. The same logic applies to the Samurai Fighter's Elegant Courtier feature and the Gloom Stalker Ranger's Iron Mind feature though both grant saving throw proficiencies, so one could *potentially* argue they aren't actually covered by the text in chapter 4.

---

If you'd really like to see [a tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1001869329795723264) from lead rules designer Jeremy Crawford, that exists too:

> The proficiency rule for backgrounds applies when you gain your background at 1st level. It has no relevance outside that context.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in ["Chapter 1: Step-By-Step Characters"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters), you choose your class (and the features you get from it) as part of step 2, but don't choose a background until step 4... That's probably another part of why the rule is in the section on backgrounds, and not the section on classes, for instance.

Comment: This one is... _extremely_ awkward.  It's a specific rule and not a general rule, yet is duplicated to almost every feature which could potentially grant skill/tool proficiency upon level-up (making it a de facto general rule).  It's in a section on background rules, yet isn't worded as something like, "If your background would give you a proficiency you already have from a different source."  And Jeremy's tweet is pretty clear, but no longer an official ruling, making it technically just his house rule.  It feels like it was meant for backgrounds, but then wanted to make it more general...

Comment: Well.. it says "if a character would gain the same proficiency from two different sources(...)" It doesn't specify that it works only on background and class (or background and race, or race and class, or only during character creation).
What could be ambiguous is whether subclasses count as the same source as the base class.